# Pass by Value and Pass by Reference

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I'm working on a project that calculate income for employees by using overloading and also pass by value + pass by reference. I need to use at least one of the functions in program to demonstrate pass-by-value; and at least one of the functions to demonstrate pass-by-reference with reference arguments.  Here is what I got so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Grosspay.h"
#include "iomanip"
using namespace std;

double income(double hours, double payrate)
{
    double grosspay = 0;
    double federaltax = .10;
    double statetax = .05;
    double totaltax;
    double netpay;
    if (hours <= 40)
    {
        grosspay = payrate * hours;
    }if (hours > 40 && hours <= 50)
    {
        grosspay = (payrate * 40) + ((hours - 40) * payrate * 1.5);
    }
    if (hours > 50)
    {
        grosspay = (payrate * 40) + (10 * payrate * 1.5) + ((hours - 50) * payrate * 2);
    }
    cout << "Grosspay weekly is: " << grosspay << endl;

    federaltax = grosspay * .10;
    cout << "Federal Tax is: " << federaltax << endl;

    statetax = grosspay * .05;
    cout << "State Tax is: " << statetax << endl;

    totaltax = federaltax + statetax;
    cout << "Total tax is: " << totaltax << endl;

    netpay = grosspay - totaltax;
    return (netpay);

}
double income(const double &year)
{
    double grosspay;
    double federaltax = .10;
    double statetax = .05;
    double totaltax;
    double netpay;

    grosspay = year / 52;
    cout << "Grosspay weekly is: " << grosspay << endl;

    federaltax = grosspay * .10;
    cout << "Federal Tax is: " << federaltax << endl;

    statetax = grosspay * .05;
    cout << "State Tax is: " << statetax << endl;

    totaltax = federaltax + statetax;
    cout << "Total Tax is: " << totaltax << endl;

    netpay = grosspay - totaltax;
    return (netpay);
}

void Grosspay::determineGrosspay()
{
    cout << "Enter 1 - Calculate payroll for hourly employee" << endl;
    cout << "Enter 2 - Calculate payroll for salary employee" << endl;
    cout << "Enter 3 - Exit" << endl;

    cout << "Federal Tax is 10% of Grosspay" << endl;
    cout << "State Tax is 5% of Grosspay" << endl;
    while (choice != 3)
    {
        cout << "\nEnter your choice: " << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Enter employee ID: " << endl;
            cin >> ID;
            cout << "Enter hours: " << endl;
            cin >> hours;
            cout << "Enter payrate: " << endl;
            cin >> payrate;

            cout << "Employee ID: " << ID << endl;
            cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
            cout << "The net pay for hourly employee: " << income(hours, payrate) << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Enter employee ID: " << endl;
            cin >> ID;
            cout << "Enter salary: " << endl;
            cin >> year;

            cout << "Employee ID: " << ID << endl;
            cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
            cout << "The net pay for salaried employee: " << income(year) << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Exited program" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Please try again!" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

One of the genius here told me that I need to put `double income(const double &year)` for the pass-by-reference. But I'm not really sure what makes the difference! I still have the same output. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: If you separate the calculations from the output, reference parameters start to make more sense.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some guidelines:

- Pass by value if the value can fit into the processor's registers and
  the parameter will not be modified.
- Pass by reference if the parameter will be modified by the function.
- Pass by constant reference if the object is larger than the
  processor's register and the parameter will not be modified.

Passing by constant reference for types like `double, float, int, char,` and `bool` doesn't make sense because these usually fit into the processor's word size.  The compiler will try to pass these values in a register.  *These POD types have no additional copying costs.* Thus, pass by value (less typing required).

Comment: I'm a beginner, so not quite understand what you saying. What should I need to do in my code to fix it?

Comment: You don't need to fix it.  An alternative is to use `double income(double year)`.

Comment: I'm totally lost now. So, this `double income(double hours, double payrate)` is pass-by-value and `double income(const double &year)` is pass-by-reference. But there will be also no changes if I do `double income(double year)`. These are what I think I understood from my knowledge. Then how do `const` and `double &year` do to make its become a reference parameter?

Comment: The syntax `double &` declares the parameter as being passed by reference (direct access).  The `const double &` declares that the parameter will be directly accessed but not modified.  The key here is "not modified".  Since the value is not modified, a copy can be passed.  Since the `double` data type can fit into a processor register, the compiler can pass the copy in a register instead of passing a pointer to the value and dereferencing the pointer for direct access.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Since he said he's a beginner I don't think you should continue the explanation with registers. How about: Pass by value if it's a bult-in type, pass by reference if it will be modified, and pass by const ref if it's a user-defined class and doesn't need to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

When you write the ampersand in the function signature, you are specifying that you are accepting a reference to the argument (in the call statement). In your function `double income(const double &year)` you are passing by reference because year is a reference to `year`.

When you pass by value, a copy of the argument is created. When you pass by reference, a copy is not made, and your variable now has the address of the argument. So if you make a change to `year` in the function (assuming that it is not const for demonstrative purposes), your value in `determineGross` will also be changed, since the value at that address was changed.

Comment: I'm understand the first paragraph that you mentioned. So what make `double income(double hours, double payrate)` become a value parameter then?

Comment: The fact that you do not lead your variable name with an ampersand. That's a very high-level way of thinking of it.