# What is the difference between pass-by-result and pass-by-value-result?

Tags: parameter-passing, pass-by-rvalue-reference

I found this explanation:

> call by value: copy going into the procedure
>
> call by result: copy going out of the procedure
>
> call by value result: copy going in, and again going out

But I don't understand, if we don't copy input, than how call by result differ from call by reference and for what we are make copy in the end of procedure. Can anybody explain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass by Value and Pass by Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156958/pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference)